# Serializing a synchronizedMap with Kryo

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, kryo

For a personal project, I have to serialize a `Collections.sychronizedMap` in Java using the Kryo-Framework. I am bound to that framework since there are other dependencies requiring it. My current attempt at this looks like so:

```
Serializer SERIALIZER = Serializer.using(KryoNamespace.builder()
                    .register(KryoNamespaces.BASIC)
                    .register(Collections.EMPTY_MAP.getClass())
                    .register(Class.forName("java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap"))
                    .build());

Map<String, String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>());

map.put("test", "123");

byte[] encoded = SERIALIZER.encode(map);

Map<String, String> decoded = SERIALIZER.decode(encoded);
```

This approach works for the serialization part, however I am struggling to get the deserialization to work. Whenever I run this piece of code, a `NullPointerException` is thrown when the `put` method on the synchronizedMap is invoked during the deserialization process. The cause of that seems to be the internal map that synchronizedMap uses, because it is null after the deserialization. But where is my mistake? Can I somehow make this code work?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers, a kryo library that is especially targeted at serializing special java types.

It can be registered in the KryoNamespace like this:

```
.register(new SynchronizedCollectionsSerializer(), Class.forName("java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap"))
```

From then on, it worked like a charm.